# Doing Recursive Function using LINQ and Delegates

Tags: c#, linq

I was under the impression that the only difference between Func and Action is that the former has to have a return value.So I thought you can call a recursive linq from either a Func or Action. I am new to C# and I am just experimenting and curious.

So I tried the following to recursively print the nested types within a Type.

```
 Type t = typeof(Lev1);
 Action<Type> p1 = null, p2 = null;
 p1 = tn =>
     {
         Console.WriteLine(tn.Name);
         tn.GetNestedTypes().Select(x => { p1(x); return x; });
     };
 p2 = tn =>
     {
         Console.WriteLine(tn.Name);
         tn.GetNestedTypes().ToList().ForEach(x => { p2(x);});
     };
 p1(t);
 Console.WriteLine("=".PadRight(50, '='));
 p2(t);
```

So the result I got was that p1 (which uses recursion from a Func-ie Select) only prints the top level whereas p2 which uses Action-ie Foreach prints all levels.

I thought Func is just a function def so recursion is valid. Sure my understanding is wrong can somebody explain

Comment: please don't repeat tags ("C# LINQ") in the title. Just leave them in the tags.

Comment: If I could teach people just one thing about queries it would be this: the result of a query expression (like your call to Select) is a *query*. A *query* and *the results of a query* are two completely different things. The result of the query expression is a *query*. If you want the *results* of that query, you're going to have to ask the query to *execute*. Now, note that writing a query that has side effects like this is a **worst practice**. Never ever do that. Execution of a query should have no side effects other than allocating its results.

Comment: thanks eric - i know it is  not a good practice to write selects with side effects .- I was only experimenting and i could not understand the result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you see only the top-level in the first implementation is because the [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0) is [lazily](https://web.archive.org/web/20150821000301/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericwhite/archive/2006/10/04/lazy-evaluation-_2800_and-in-contrast_2c00_-eager-evaluation_2900_.aspx) [evaluated](http://www.nullable.se/2008-05/linq_and_lazy_evaluation). It only starts returning values when it needs to, for example when you iterate it (or when you call [`Sum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-6.0) or a number of other functions). If you add a [`ToList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=net-6.0) call after the `Select`, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

**You must *force* the IEnumerable** -- it is lazy! (It needn't always be, but be wary with LINQ methods!)

In this case, you discard the results (and the actions!). Oh, well!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `.ToList()` to the first `Select()` call because Linq functions are *lazy*. In the second call the recursion works because of `List<>.ForEach()` (which as the name stands does exactly what `foreach` statement does).